# GitHub Actions: env: Use pre-defined environment variables on RHS within env section

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I would like to declare some environment variables in a top level **env** section in my **main.yml** whose values use some pre-defined environment variables such as those documented [in the GitHub Actions documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables).  However, it appears I cannot use those pre-defined variables in the right hand side of my env section.  For example:

```
env:
  resourceGroup: ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}
```

Is there a way to make it so any step that needs ${resourceGroup} can get it without having to manually define it within each step?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I tried the following two ways.

```
env:
  resourceGroup1: ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}-${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}
  resourceGroup2: ${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}

jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: test1
        run: echo ${{ env.resourceGroup1 }}
      - name: test2
        run: echo ${{ env.resourceGroup2 }}
```

In both cases, the results were obtained correctly.

[image]

However, in the case of env as a result, the former has not yet been evaluated. Maybe you can use the latter.

[image]

Comment: Ah, you are right. The syntax he was using was incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I built a GitHub Action that will do it for you: [Add Env vars](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-env-vars).

Use it as the first step in a job in your workflow, and pass in JSON-stringified env vars as the `map` parameter. They need to be set for each job - they will only be set for all subsequent steps in a job.

Here is your test case, using the Add Env vars:

```
  test:  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup env
        uses: jwulf/add-env-vars-action@master
        with:
          map: '{"resourceGroup1": "${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}", "resourceGroup2": "${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}"}'   
      - name: test1
        run: echo ${{ env.resourceGroup1 }}
      - name: test2
        run: echo ${{ env.resourceGroup2 }}
```

Comment: It was the "I hope all the readers are having a great day." - I was like, "*This guy*. Imma build it."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like set-env works as well: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-environment-variable-set-env